# \back slash charectar and . in grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am confused about the backslash character \ and single quotations inside grep. From my understanding it preserves the literal meaning. For example

if I do `echo 'This is \.`, it gives me `This is \.`

However, if I want to match any actual .(period) I need to use '\.' to escape the special meaning of . in regular expression. 
For example if a have a file demo.txt taken from [example from this website](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/)

[image: Problem output]

My question is how is the ' ' not preserving the literal value in this case for grep? This is proving to be very confusing for me. Any explanations would be very helpful.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes protect characters from interpretation by the *shell*, but `grep` still treats the argument as a regular expression.

You can turn this behavior off by running grep with the `-F` or `--fixed-strings` option:

```
grep -F 'purchase.' demo.txt
```

The single quotes are not necessary as none of those `p`, `u`, `r`, `c`, `h`, `a`, `s`, `e` or `.` characters are special to the shell:

```
grep -F purchase. demo.txt
```

Or you could use `grep` without `-F` but escape the `.` regular expression operator with `\`:

```
grep 'purchase\.' demo.txt
```

The single quotes are so that `\` (which is also special for the shell; a quoting operator there) is passed literally to `grep`. Or you can use the `\` shell quoting operator to quote itself:

```
grep purchase\\. demo.txt
```

You can also use the `[set]` regex operator to match on a literal `.`:

```
grep 'purchase[.]' demo.txt
```

Again, `[set]` is *also* a shell operator (a globbing operator there) so needs to be quoted as well (here with single quotes again).